# Referencing variable workbooks in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, vlookup

I have a scenario where a user creates a workbook, then this workbook (let's call it A) is assigned a variable.  Later on down the line, the user creates a second workbook (let's call it B), which is assigned another variable.  The names of these workbooks are not fixed, thus they are always variables.

Now I want to do a VLOOKUP in Workbook A of a value contained in Workbook B using VBA.  Is this possible?  If so, what would the code look like?

Here's my attempt at this, which didn't go over too well with Excel:

Range("X7").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(K7,[B]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"

Where 'B' is the variable name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
oCell.Formula = "VLOOKUP(" & oKeyCell.Address & ", " & oSearchRange.Address(External:=True) & ", 2, FALSE)"
```

In other words, rather than calculating what the address is in code, let Excel do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is good except you forgot one thing:

```
"=VLOOKUP(K7,[" & Book "]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"
```

You need an extra `&` sign after the `Book`:

```
"=VLOOKUP(K7,[" & Book & "]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"
```